# check if two vectors are equal python

Tags: python, numpy

I have one vector called cm which does not change

```
cm = np.array([[99,99,0]])
```

and another vector called pt. that I want to loop through certain values. but when the two are equal, I want it skip over and not perform the operation. for the sake of this post I just said to have it print out the value of pt, but I actually have a whole host of operations to run. here is my code

```
for i in range (95,103): 
    for j in range (95,103):
        pt = np.array([[i,j,0]])
        if pt == cm:
            continue
        print pt
```

i have tried changing the 4th line to

```
if pt.all == cm.all
```

but that prints everything, including the one I want to skip 
and then if i turn it into

```
if pt.all() == cm.all()
```

that also doesn't work. what is the difference between those two anyway?

does anyone know how i can fix it so that when pt = [99,99,0] it will skip the operations and go back to the beginning of the loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for `(pt == cm).all()`, although if floats are involved `np.allclose(pt, cm)` is probably a better idea in case you have numerical errors.

(1) `pt.all == cm.all`

This checks to see whether the two *methods* are equal:

```
>>> pt.all
<built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x16cbbe0>
>>> pt.all == cm.all
False
```

(2) `pt.all() == cm.all()`

This checks to see see whether the result of `all` matches in each case.  For example:

```
>>> pt
array([[99, 99,  0]])
>>> pt.all()
False
>>> cm = np.array([10, 10, 0])
>>> cm.all()
False
>>> pt.all() == cm.all()
True
```

(3) `(pt == cm).all()`

This creates an array testing to see whether the two are equal, and returns whether the result is all True:

```
>>> pt
array([[99, 99,  0]])
>>> cm
array([[99, 99,  0]])
>>> pt == cm
array([[ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> (pt == cm).all()
True
```

One downside is that this constructs a temporary array, but often that's not an issue in practice.

Aside: when you're writing nested loops with numpy arrays you've usually made a mistake somewhere.  Python-level loops are slow, and so you lose a lot of the benefits you get from using `numpy` in the first place. But that's a separate issue.